# SnackbarContentLayout class not found after migration to AndroidX

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, android-snackbar, snackbar

After migration to AndroidX my app crashes after calling **Snackbar.make()** method. The error looks like

`Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.SnackbarContentLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.internal.SnackbarContentLayout"`

It's strange that internal **Snackbar** method **make()** is still trying to access **SnackbarContentLayout** class in old support package instead new material's one. Please advice what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE

Finally I found a solution. There is a custom layout in my project which overrides 
Snackbar's `design_layout_snackbar_include` and it had wrong class in root **view** tag:

```
<view
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  class="android.support.design.internal.SnackbarContentLayout"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom">
```

I changed it to `com.google.android.material.snackbar.SnackbarContentLayout`

Comment: show me you xml code

Comment: show your work. Check import `import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Snackbar is imported from material package. `import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;`

Comment: @Jaydeepchatrola it's an activity with 'androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout' root

Answer (score 0):

ensure that your project is set up to migrate old packages to Androidx by including this in your gradle.properties file:

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: It's enabled. I had used Android Studio built-in migration refactor tool